# Android studio preview screen showing blank

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The problem is that when I use TabLayout the screen turns black and there is no error, when I run the emulator screen there is no problem with the emulator screen
I hope to find a solution
........
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYPkF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19JR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlzIh.png)

I made a project again and changed Theme
the  problem is still there

Comment: my suggestion would be, try android studio Flamingo or Giraffe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this methdod:

1. Open File -> Project Structure
2. Upgrade the `gradle version to 7.4` and `gradle plugin version to 7.3.0`
3. Invalidate cache
4. Restart the Android Studio